# rewrite condition for directory along with file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Any one please help me.I am new to .htaccess

I want to check the following condition

```
RewriteCond : IF !index.html AND !app/facebookapp/{[a-zA-Z0-9-/]}.html
RewriteRule : .....
```

My code is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.html 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} app/facebookapp/^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ 
RewriteRule ......
```

its not working

And one more question

if the request url is `header.html`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} header.html$ 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ position.php?position=$1 [L]
```

`$l` will return `header`.

if the request url is `app/facebookapp/header.html`
we write the same above condition `$l` will return `app/facebookapp/header`.my question is how to get only the filename ??

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1:

Looks to me like you've got the ^ character in the wrong place.  In regex syntax, that denotes the beginning of the text but you've got some text before it.  You could put it at the front of the thing, but I think in this case you could just get rid of it.  Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.html 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} app/facebookapp/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ 
RewriteRule ......
```

Part 2:

You'll need two matching groups, and to only use the second one in the right-hand side.  The first one includes / as a valid character, and the second one does not.  Let me know if this works better:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} header.html$ 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ position.php?position=$2 [L]
```

Comment: thanks Benjamin Cox....1 question answer is correct....2nd question...`$2` return only the last character if `app/facebookapp/head.html`....it return `d`

Comment: whoops - forgot the bit in between the groups....  I've updated it, will you try the new version?

Comment: without `?` working well eg : `^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ `